# How do i resolve this error " SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Should the data be sent as a JSON Object or should it be sent as a string.
These are the JSON values that needs to be sent to the url.

```
  var d={
  "cand_name": "markzuck",
  "candidate_management_cand_info__pkey": 14,
  "candidate_management_job_id__fkey": "1",
  "cand_email": "jagadeesh.korikana@gmail.com",
  "cand_altemail": "b@gmail.com",
  "cand_contact": "6576575576",
  }; 

  var url =  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(d),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(response => { 
       alert(JSON.stringify(d));
       return response.json(); 
    }).then(data => { 
       alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log(d);
       alert(err);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This error often occurs when something you try to parse as JSON is not really a JSON string.

It looks like you actually get HTML (due to a server error or something) and trying to parse it as JSON in `response.json();`.

I would suggest checking `response.status` and only if it's a valid response parsing it with `response.json();`.

Comment: Thanks for the  quick reply.It says internal Server error.I have written the middleware in nodejs and i'm using react as frontend.

Comment: Yes, the 5xx one. Generally, that means that there's something wrong with the server and it can't handle your request. Try to send the data manually (via Postman for example) and look for the response. Maybe you will get to the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send JSON data as a string, instead of as a JS Object. Check the [MDN documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) related to this.

Also, make sure that the JSON string is valid using any json lint available online. My personal favorite is [JSONEditorOnline](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)